node --env-file=.env is not directing to the correct folder?
Trying to teach myself environment variables, it took me a few minutes to learn dotenv, and I saw node now since v20 has a built-in similar feature. They are all in the same folder
//.env
HELLO = werld

//test.js
const {HELLO} = process.env;
console.log(`Hello ${HELLO}`);
console.log(`Hello ${process.env.HELLO}`);
console.log(process.env.HELLO);
console.log(process.env);

I issue the command
node --env-file=.env test.js

according to the docs and the videos I've watched and all the results come back undefined. process.env I imagine sends to the default file path, which is far from where I need it. Might be worth mentioning my laptop uses OneDrive. This seems to be a fairly new feature, so i didn't find a lot of information except the docs, and everything else was nearly identical. I also tried quotations in every form, but it seems it's using the default .env instead of the one I created.
I tried changing quotations and altering file paths.

I can't reproduce the problem. The posted code works for me. Please provide more details. Which version of Node do you use? How is the file structure?

how did you run the env?

@AbdullaNilam What does it mean to "run the env"? Do you mean the call node --env-file=.env test.js?

What is "the default .env"? Do you have multiple .env files? What is the working directory?
